Excel: conditional summing of rows matching predefined strings
I need to monitor the number of different appointments employees are providing in each calendar week, meaning that it should also take into account the employee's vacations. I couldn't figure it out how to write a formula for calculating the red numbers. Tried combining SUMIF and TEXTSPLIT but no luck.

Excel file can be downloaded here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/o2df69n97unt1nm7wzhyz/monitoring-appointments.xlsx?rlkey=frynz9lnzamkaxothzrcnugt1&e=1&dl=1

Try using the following formula, this should definitely work as per the conditions outlined in the OP:


=LET(
     a, INDEX($B$4:$E$7,,XMATCH(I$3,$B$3:$E$3)),
     SUM(a)- SUM(SUMIF($A$4:$A$7,IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT($H4,", "),),a)))


• For older versions could try the following:
=SUM(INDEX($B$4:$E$7,,MATCH(I$3,$B$3:$E$3,0)))-
 SUM((ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&$A$4:$A$7&"*",$H4,0)))*(I$3=$B$3:$E$3)*$B$4:$E$7)


Or, can use SUMPRODUCT() in place of SUM()
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($B$4:$E$7,,MATCH(I$3,$B$3:$E$3,0)))-
SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&$A$4:$A$7&"*",$H4,0)))*(I$3=$B$3:$E$3)*$B$4:$E$7)



thanks! Why it's giving "#NAME?" after pressing ENTER? It says the formula includes unrecognized text.

What version of Excel you are using and what is the list separator you are using is it comma or semicolon?

Comma and MS Office Professional Plus 2019 Version 1808 Build 10412.20006)

If you are using Excel 2019, then you said in your Post that you have tried using TEXTSPLIT() how does TEXTSPLIT() work with Excel 2019? Can you explain?

It didn't work out. However, I tried using it as some googling led to this function

@st4co4 try out the updated formula using SUM() or SUMPRODUCT()
